# Skybox OpenGL ES2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am implementing a Skybox in my OpenGL application.

Is it more common to use a single texture like this [one](https://www.google.ca/search?q=skybox&espv=2&biw=1667&bih=832&tbm=isch&imgil=xy9d4t04Dn5IiM%253A%253BK-F5emXooGaWFM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fgithub.com%25252Fjrenner%25252Fgdx-proto%25252Fissues%25252F9&source=iu&pf=m&fir=xy9d4t04Dn5IiM%253A%252CK-F5emXooGaWFM%252C_&usg=__o6mkBIGI0p1BaVfOwS5Ig5LiXd0%3D&ved=0CDEQyjdqFQoTCMPH2ZXHg8cCFcyrHgodBbwD3A&ei=gHa6VcOHL8zXeoX4juAN#imgrc=xy9d4t04Dn5IiM%3A&usg=__o6mkBIGI0p1BaVfOwS5Ig5LiXd0%3D) and use UV mapping to pull out the six sides.

Or is it more common to just use one texture for each of the six sides using something like [this](http://www.redsorceress.com/skybox.html) site provides.

The advantage to me in using one texture is that you save overhead by not using unnecessary texture units. HOWEVER, the sacrifice here is obviously image resolution. If you use a single 2048x2048 texture as show each side of the skybox only has 512x512 pixels to work with. Where one texture for each side quadruples the available pixels....

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it more common to use a single texture like this one and use UV
>   mapping to pull out the six sides

Using a single texture is recommended, since it would reduce the amount of state switches and thus yields in most cases a better performance. Combinding multiple texture in one big texture is called 'Texture atlas' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas and is used in a lot of applications, to reduce the number of separate textures.

> If you use a single 2048x2048 texture as show each side of the skybox
>   only has 512x512 pixels to work with. Where one texture for each side
>   quadruples the available pixels....

This is not really and argument, because you could combine six 2048x2048 textures in one big texture.

My personal recommendations for enviroment maps (skyboxes are enviroment maps,too), is to use cube maps https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture . With cubemaps you're combining both advantages (only one texture bind + easy texture coordinates) and cubemaps have more usages, for example simple reflections.

Comment: Is there not a limitation on texture sizes that can be bound to? I know on my phone it is 4096x4096. I will look into cubemaps.

Comment: Yes, there is a device specific maximum texture size. Since combining six 2048x2048 in one 4096x4096 is a pretty difficult task you are required here to use either a cubemap or 3D textures. But before using giant textures on mobile devices, you really need to think twice if it's really necessary, because memory bandwith is in many applications the bottleneck and could really hurt your performance.

Comment: I have been looking at cubemapping. For Android it seems you need to use the glTexImage2D call which requires you to pass all pixel data. Wherease before I was using texImage2D which is simply a pointer to the bitmap object. This seems memory intensive...

Comment: got it working thanks. Any leads on places to buy/download high-res pre-made skyboxes?